# How many resources does a visit or more than one consume in a ubuntu VPS?

Tags: server, vps

I am using AWS taking advantage of the grace period to start internships, at the moment I do not have any more questions except the consumption of resources or others with the same reference.

Most private or proprietary servers using a virtual machine are the following most impressive specifications I think:

1 CPU Xeon / QuadCore 1GB Ram
100GB of storage
1 TB transfer
(Bandwidth)

Many of these data are billed for consumption if there is consumption of resources a charge is generated but there is no, others make them through a fixed monthly cost, well getting to the point ... From the title of the topic, what I would like to know is how much resources consumes a visitor, 100 visitors, 1000 visitors or more examples, the resources they consume based on:

1 CPU Xeon / QuadCore 1GB Ram
100GB of storage
1 TB transfer
(Bandwidth)

If you need any other important information or a resource that does not specify please mention it, it would not be necessary to teach me how to perform the calculations so I can do it thank you very much.

regards

Comment: Impossible to answer. You need to check this in the aws portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the title of the topic, what I would like to know is how much resources consumes a visitor, 100 visitors, 1000 visitors or more examples, the resources they consume based on:

What are you serving? A static 1kiB HTML page? I did some quick tests on a server I have:

- Simple PHP script (milliseconds execution time): 950 requests per second
- Static HTML, 1kiB: 2500 requests per second
- Complex PHP with queries: 15 requests per second.

In neither of these cases bandwidth was a issue. However, I easily saturate the 1Gb/s link (or my 500Mb/s home connection) with one big file download, without *any* noticeable impact on CPU or memory on the server.

So in short; it depends on your workload. You should benchmark your *actual* application, using for instance `ab2`.